# D3 Legend Transition On Update

Tags: graph, d3.js, transition

This graph that I'm making has a few problems but the one that I can't figure out is the legend transition. I've got it so there are correct colors and everything lines up but when the new data is added, the text just overlaps with the old text. When I try and select the rectangles and text to exit which is commented out in the attached code below, the legend's colors will end up being the same and the text still overlaps. Here is my graph:

http://jsbin.com/ETOBOfO/1/edit

Could anyone help point out what is going wrong? Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the old legend before drawing a new one:

```
svg.selectAll(".legend").remove();
var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
    ...
```